# How to apply transformations to mesh geometry

Tags: qt, mesh, qt3d

On Qt3D, an entity can have these two components:

1. `Qt3DRender::QGeometryRenderer` component which contains the **mesh geometry** data like vertex **positions** and **normals**.
2. `Qt3DCore::QTransform` component which contains the **rotations**, **translations** and **scalings**.

---

I intend to export the mesh data as STL with all the **transformations** applied to **mesh geometry**. I mean, all rotations and translations need to be applied to vertex positions...

When I access the mesh geometry data, like below, the transformations are not applied to geometry.

```
mesh->geometry()->attributes().at(i)->buffer()->data();
```

How can I apply the **transformations** to the **geometry**?

---

The `Qt3DCore::QTransform` component gives me a [4x4 Matrix](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.9/qt3dcore-qtransform.html#matrix-prop), but my vertex positions are `3x1`, I don't know how to apply this 4x4 matrix into my `3x1` vertex positions.

Comment: A faster solution than iterating over all vertices yourself and applying Mariam's solution could be to stack all vertices in the columns of a `QGenericMatrix` (i.e. [v1|v2|v3|...]) and then multiply your transformation from the left side: transform * vertMatrix. This should result in a matrix where each column is the transformed vertex. The guys at Qt probably implemented a faster matrix multiplication algorithm than simple iteration.

Comment: @FlorianBlume Right, I'm going to try your solution. Thanks ☺

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the math of transformations, to transform a vector with a 4x4 transformation matrix, everything has to be in [homogeneous coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates#Use_in_computer_graphics_and_computer_vision). You do this by adding a fourth component to the vector and setting it to one and then just multiply it with the (already homogeneous) 4x4 matrix. so:

```
QVector3D oldVec = QVector3D(x,y,z);     //this is your 3x1 vertex position
QVector4D newVec = QVector4D(oldVec.x(), oldVec.y(), oldVec.z(), 1);    //added 1 as fourth component
QVector4D transformedVec = matrix*newVec;    //matrix is your 4x4 transformation matrix
//transformedVec is now what you need but with the fourth component still being the 1, so we just leave it out:
QVector3D transformedVec3D = QVector3D(transformedVec.x(), transformedVec.y(), transformedVec.z());
```

To read more about the math behind it, you can check out [this link](https://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/affine/matrix4x4/index.htm).

Comment: I see I've got some competition now answering Qt3D questions, very nice! Even less agony for the rest trying to use it :) But maybe mention the term [homogeneous coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates#Use_in_computer_graphics_and_computer_vision), that's what the vertices have to be in but are not when represented by a `3x1` vector.

Comment: haha I'm trying to give something back as well :) and yes thanks for the addition!